# ParseError in python using etree

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to process a couple of files, by taking it from a directory using  glob library and it gives me an error. I think maybe is an error while is trying to parse the list that contains the name of files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
import glob as g


path = g.glob('C:\Users\Desktop\*_LEITURAS*')
data = []

for archiv in path:     
    for (ev, el) in et.iterparse(archiv):
            if el.tag == 'NOME_DISTRITO': nome = el.text
            if el.tag == 'NR_CPE': nr = el.text
            if el.tag == "LEITURA":
                inner = {}
                inner['NOME_DISTRITO'] = nome
                inner['NR_CPE'] = nr
                for i in el:
                    inner[i.tag] = i.text        
                data.append(inner)

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The error:

> ipdb> ParseError: ParseErr...mn 0',),)

Does anyone can help me with the error?

Comment: it would help enormously to post raw data that reproduces the error, have you looked at the file itself and done a little debugging to isolate the error?

Comment: Can you post the full error trace back? My guess is that the `ParseError` is coming from the `et` object: i.e. you may be dealing with bad XML.

Comment: The error I get is when I'm trying to work reading all the files from a directory. If I work with a single file it works, but when I read severals files from a directory it gives me the error. I am pretty sure that all files are ok. Maybe the `et.iterparse()` doesn`t accept an array with the name of the files ofmy directory @EdChum

Comment: You need to add `.xml` to your `glob()` as non-xml files are possibly being read in.